# CakePhp: Don't display ONE warning

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, warnings, try-catch

I've one place in my code where I free some ingres resources, and I've no way to know if the parameter is valid ingres resource.

So I would like to do it anyway(except if empty() ).

I'm try-catching it, but when this isnt a valid resource, I got the exception catched by cakePhp and then it display the debug message, and it mess with the encoding the whole site.

I know that I can't deactivate the debugging for the whole site, but the website is under development and it's not what I want.

So, how to manage cakePhp to DON'T display this warning for this exception on this line(I also don't want to ignore all errors of this type).

Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: I find it very unlikely that it wouldn't be possible to check the resource's validity. Try `var_dump( $resource )` and check what type it returns if the resource isn't valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress errors/warnings with the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) but without seeing some code can't advise more specifically.

`@mysql_connect('localhost', 'root, 'pass');`

`@file('file.txt');`

etc.

Or you could try ~

```
Configure::write('debug', 0); // turn off debugging

/* your code here where you don't want any errors */

Configure::write('debug',2); // turn on debugging
```

I'm sure there's a proper way to check for valid data however. some code in your original post would help

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a persistent connection, PHP will free it automatically: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php